# Removing specific spaces

Tags: java

**Problem**

I wrote a Java program, where at a certain position, I have a String named `encrypted` that looks like this (including the line breaks):

```
e a f i   |  2 1 2 3 
b j m _   |  1 3 4 2 
n h c k   |  4 2 1 3 
_ o l p   |  1 4 3 4
```

(The `_` should be spaces too, but I changed them to `_` for clarification here.)

At this point, I have to remove line breaks and the `|`, which I do with `replaceAll()`.

The String now looks like this:

`e a f i     2 1 2 3b j m _     1 3 4 2n h c k     4 2 1 3_ o l p     1 4 3 4`

My problem now is that I want to remove all the spaces except the ones changed to `_` here.

So I have to remove

- one space between two letters
- one space between two numbers
- a unknown number of spaces between any ASCII-Character and a number

**Minimal Working example**

```
public class Test {
    private static String encrypted = "e a f i   |  2 1 2 3\nb j m _   |  1 3 4 2\nn h c k   |  4 2 1 3\n_ o l p   |  1 4 3 4";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        encrypted = encrypted.replace("\n", "");
        encrypted = encrypted.replace("|", "");
        //Here I have to remove the spaces
    }
}
```

**Question**

How can I achieve my goal? Are regular expressions the way to go here, or are there good alternatives?

Comment: The underscores are actually spaces, I think?

Comment: Yes the underscores are spaces, I just replaced it here for clarification.

Comment: It looks like you should parse your initial input into a dedicated data structure (maybe 2 2-dimensional arrays of `char`) and work on those instead of trying to implement your entire algorithm on top of a string-representation of your data.

String representations are for humans. Most other data structures are for computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
private static String encrypted = "e a f i   |  2 1 2 3\nb j m     |  1 3 4 2\nn h c k   |  4 2 1 3\n  o l p   |  1 4 3 4";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    encrypted = encrypted.replace("\n", "");
    encrypted = encrypted.replace("  |  ", "");
    encrypted = encrypted.replace("  ", "_");
    encrypted = encrypted.replace(" ", "");
    encrypted = encrypted.replace("_", " ");
    System.out.println(encrypted);
}
```

Output: eafi2123bjm 1342nhck4213 olp1434

EDIT:
If you dont want _'s to be changed:

```
private static String encrypted = "e a f i   |  2 1 2 3\nb j m     |  1 3 4 2\nn h c k   |  4 2 1 3\n  o l p   |  1 4 3 4";
final static String PLACEHOLDER = "placeholder";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    encrypted = encrypted.replace("\n", "");
    encrypted = encrypted.replace("  |  ", "");
    encrypted = encrypted.replace("  ", PLACEHOLDER);
    encrypted = encrypted.replace(" ", "");
    encrypted = encrypted.replace(PLACEHOLDER, " ");
    System.out.println(encrypted);
}
```

Comment: Now if any of the characters actually start as `_` you've turned them into spaces ...

Comment: Unfortunately not really, because of the reason mentioned by @JoachimSauer.

Comment: Do you mean when the input-String contains a _? Well the 2 _ in the code could be replaced with anything. They are just placeholders to safe the position of those locations

Comment: Yes, basically whatever character you pick for replacing the spaces with will end up being replaced itself unless you add some second layer of escaping... the beauty of in-band signalling.

Comment: Edited the answer. Now using a placeholder-String

Comment: Exactly, just think of the underscores to also be spaces. I just used underscores here to make a difference between the spaces that should and the ones that shouldn't be removed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use your edit either, because it is random where the spaces are that should be removed, so I cant replace them with placeholder before.

Comment: Either I dont understand your question or the code is doing exactly what you needed. Could you give me an example-String where this code does not work?

Comment: Oh, I was a bit fast commenting. Thank you very much!